# Sharepoint Tasks List "Assigned To"

Tags: sharepoint-2007

Is there any way i can convert **Assigned To** field in sharepoint Tasks list to Dropdown, by default it will be from peoples and group search box.

Using designer converting that field to drop down gives nothing for me

Please help me on this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but it's not trivial - you need to develop **a custom field type** similar to the built-in *Person or Group* type but using a drop-down list instead of `PeopleEditor` (commonly known as a "people picker").

If you want to go this way, read the [Custom Field Types for SharePoint 2007](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd727508.aspx) article and check one of many projects available at CodePlex (e.g. [Sharepoint Skype status field](http://skypestatusfield.codeplex.com/)) to learn more.